# Modify instance parameter before the instance on points node, based on the position

Tags: instances

I'm trying to make a grass field, and make flowers bloom when a 'sun' approaches the ground.
I have already solved the problem of making the grass taller and increasing the flower size, but I would like to add the blooming animation of the flower. Right now I have a node group that given an input between 0 and 1 creates a flower, closed with 0 and fully open with 1.
The problem is that when I try to instanciate flowers on top of the grass I just get the same flower repeated over and over, based on the distance between the 'sun' and the original position of the flower.
Basically I would need to know the distance between the flower and the sun before instancing the flower.
Does someone have a nice workaround for this issue?
[image]

Comment: Did you 'Realize Instances'?

Comment: Yes I've already tried that, but no success. I would need to give every flower a different input, like I do for the scale and rotation